# WooCommerce - Show ex. VAT/incl. VAT label

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In my WooCommerce store I have setup taxes for all European countries, but for all other countries there a no taxes. So I have made one tax line with a wilcard "*" for all other countries with 0 percent tax.

Futher more we also have business customers (custom user role) which also are eligible to get 0 tax (handled by another plugin).

The prices shows the correct price, but it is important for us to have a label show with the product that shows if the price is "incl. VAT" or "Ex. VAT"?

Have tried almost all settings, snippets I could find etc., but can not find a solution :(

Anyone who can help with that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need insert this snippets for Showing 0 value taxes:

```
/* Show at cart/checkout */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_hide_zero_taxes', '__return_false' );

/* Show at the order */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_hide_zero_taxes', '__return_false' );
```

**Source:** https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/How-Taxes-Work-in-WooCommerce#showing-0-value-taxes

Answer (score 1):

there's an option for price display suffix, where you can set a label for VAT.

Go to: WooCommerce > Settings > Tax. This tab is only visible if taxes are enabled.

More info: [Woo docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/setting-up-taxes-in-woocommerce/#section-10)

Comment: Yes but it show the label regardless if the prices are with or without taxes :(

Comment: I see, so it will show something like "Incl VAT: 0€", is that it?